# Key Value Regex Patterns

Tags: regex

I am new to regex and I am trying to capture a series of key value pairs using a  pattern. The values I am looking to capture come with a key, line by line, with an "="  as the separator :

```
Field1        = value1
Field2        = value2
Field3        = value3
```

Could someone help me define a regex pattern to capture the values, I am working with the following pattern:

```
(\w+)=(.+?)\={1}?
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following *regex* (*using [Positive Lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)*) to capture all the values :

```
(?<=\=\s).+
```

see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/Q4KKmy/5)

Comment: Hi Siam, thanks a lot for the reply and the demo explanation! The values I am trying to capture can also include complex values such as : 123@abc.com, abc- det - FLP, VCN:20161115:74055:5, 99.709 . For some values, only half the string is captured and I need to have everything until the next line included. I am looking at the '+' following the 'w' which I understand is 'greedy'. Would you know how I can modify the last bit to capture everything until the end of the line? Thanks for your inputs, much appreciated

Comment: Thanks Siam, exactly as needed. The demo was also useful :)

Comment: You're most Welcome!! :-)

Comment: You don't need to escape the `=`

Comment: Dude, I'm not your bro.

Comment: @ThomasAyoub ohk.. soz.. nvm :/

Comment: That was a joke, see [Dude, I'm not your bro.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h3OCOXwcGNA) (and have my upvote)

Comment: @siam, I am trying to run this pattern as part of a vba script to scrape emails. currently, it does not work and apparently it could be that vba does not support lookbehind.. just wanted to check with you if you have any other ideas? many thanks in advance

Comment: @siam, ah ok. I guess that's a fair trade.. ;) coming up